# How do I set the order of nodes for a SLURM job?

Tags: slurm

I have a slurm setup with various partitions. In my slurm.conf, I have a list of computers that can run the jobs for my partition, eg.

```
PartitionName=hi Nodes=rack[0-4],pc1,pc2 MaxTime=INFINITE State=UP Priority=1000 PreemptMode=off
```

pc1 and pc2 have 3 cores available, the racks have 4 cores each. If I submit 4 jobs at once, it will allocate 3 to pc1 and 1 to pc2. I would like to alter the order that these are allocated. Specifically, I would like them to go on the racks first, then pc2, then pc1.

Any thoughts?

Ta,
James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `weight` parameter in `slurm.conf` when defining your nodes

From the [manpage](http://slurm.schedmd.com/slurm.conf.html):

> Weight
>       The priority of the node for scheduling purposes. All things being equal, jobs will be allocated the nodes with the lowest weight which
>   satisfies their requirements.

So for instance set `weight=1000` for `pc4`, `weight=100` for `pc3` and `weight=10` for the `racks`.